# Reason for error when saving shapefile in a new projection

Tags: qgis

I tried to save a WG84 shapefile as a UTM 16N projection and got the following error: "Export to vector file failed.
Error: creation of layer failed (OGR error:Failed to open Shapefile `HF patients who are not 30 day readmissions in UTM 16N.shp'.

Comment: Does it work with a shorter filename, without blanks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Andrej wrote in his comment, a **shorter name without whitespaces** should work.

Otherwise, I would also check the **path length** to the directory where the shapefile is to be stored. I have already have issues with long paths and solved them by saving my shapefile on D: directory (for instance).